# Any connection between Eddington and Maclane?

Tags: category-theory, physics, philosophy

I am reading "The Nature of the Physical World" by Sir A.S. Eddington.

[The Nature of the Physical World](http://henry.pha.jhu.edu/Eddington.2008.pdf)

Written in 1928, AFAIK it predates any category theory or thinking, what with MacLane still two years away from graduating Yale at this point.

Yet as I read it, I can't help but get the impression Sir Eddington was already thinking categorically: he speaks of a world-building in terms of relations only, speaks of space and time as categories, clearly states the limits of set theory and laments that there are no other systems; in fact, MacLane's "adjoints are everywhere" quip adequately describes the underlying philosophy of "The nature of the physical world" .

The most modern mathematical review of Eddington's ideas that I could find is this 2004 PhD Thesis, but it doesn't touch on category theory.

[Sir Arthur Eddignton and the foundations of physics](https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0603/0603146.pdf)

Given the prominence that Eddington had at that time, I find it unlikely that MacLane was not exposed to his writings and, as I'm asking, I actually believe it might have had a great influence on his categorical thinking.

*Is there any reference or literature that can confirm (or deny) this connection?*

*For those that have read it, am I just suffering from categorical pareidolia?*

Comment: One of the chapters is called "Probability Leads to Uncertainty".  That's exactly backwards: uncertainty is what leads to probability. $\qquad$

Comment: I haven't read it, but this seems like a huge stretch to me.  None of the things you describe sound like they have more than a very superficial connection to category theory, especially to the beginnings of category theory.

Comment: EW, if you "haven't read it", then all you are commenting on is my inadequate wording,not the work itself.  MH -- left adjoint, right adjoint, chicken and the egg.  If you take Unc. as a start, it leads to Prob; equally, if you use Prob. as a start, it leads to Unc. Either way, the CORRECTNESS of the book is not the question; it's status as an inspiration for MacLane is.